# working with paired data across groups in the tidyverse

Tags: r, grouping, tidyverse, reshape2

I have multiple observations from each of a few groups and I'd like to make a matrix of QQ plots (or another type of plot), comparing each group to every other group.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(27599)
n <- 30
d <- data_frame(person = c(rep('Alice', n),
                           rep('Bob', n),
                           rep('Charlie', n),
                           rep('Danielle', n)),
                score = c(rnorm(n = n),
                          rnorm(n = n, mean = 0.1),
                          rnorm(n = n, sd = 2),
                          rnorm(n = n, mean = 0.3, sd = 1.4)))

by_hand <- data_frame(a = sort(d$score[d$person == 'Alice']),
                      b = sort(d$score[d$person == 'Bob']),
                      c = sort(d$score[d$person == 'Charlie']),
                      d = sort(d$score[d$person == 'Danielle']))

pairs(x = by_hand,
      lower.panel = function(x, y) { points(x, y); abline(0, 1);})
```

Here, I've manipulated the data by hand and used graphics::pairs() to make the plot.  Can the same be done inside the tidyverse?

Here's what I've tried.

```
d %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(score = sort(score)) %>% 
  glimpse()
```

This seems promising.

```
d %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(score = sort(score)) %>% 
  spread(key = person, value = score)
```

This gives the 'duplicate identifiers' error.
Maybe reshape2 would be better to use  here?

```
d %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  mutate(score = sort(score)) %>% 
  dcast(formula = score ~ person)
```

This creates a data.frame with 120 rows, and most of the values (90 per person) are NA.  How can I create a wide data.frame without introducing so many NA?

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable that links the row position for each person. Try

```
by_tidyverse <- d %>% 
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(rowID=1:n(),
         score=sort(score)
  ) %>% 
  spread(key = person, value = score) %>%
  select(-rowID)

pairs(x = by_tidyverse, lower.panel = function(x, y) { points(x, y); abline(0, 1);})
```